# Parse nginx log and export to BigQuery

Tags: json, parsing, nginx, logging, google-bigquery

I have nginx log files containing the following pattern:

> 111.111.111.xxx - - [16/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /some.php?action_name=&idsite=4430 HTTP/1.1" 200 290 .....

What I need is to import it into BigQuery. Or first I convert the log into json format and then BigQuery can ingest it easily.

Any handy solution?

Comment: Yes you can, see this https://blog.pkhamre.com/logging-to-logstash-json-format-in-nginx/

Comment: That's not the question. The problem is I already have the logs and want to convert to Json format.

Comment: Yes log stash can do that. You can have input which reads from existing file and then stdout or output it to a JSON file

Answer (score 0):

For parsing the logs: You can parse the logs using logstash logstash grok filters.

Logstash output plugin: BigQuery Plugin can be used to send logs to BigQuery. For sending data to BigQuery, data should be highly structured, So, I will suggest parsing and conversting it into key value pairs and then send to BigQuery using BigQuery Filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Nginx access log to use json format:

```
log_format json '{ '
'"time": "$time_local", '
'"remote_addr": "$remote_addr", '
'"remote_user": "$remote_user", '
'"request_url": "$request", '
'"request_time": "$request_time", '
'"response_status": "$status", '
'"response_size": "$body_bytes_sent", '
'"referrer": "$http_referer", '
'"agent": "$http_user_agent", '
'"forwarded_for": "$http_x_forwarded_for", '
'"host": "$host" '
'}';
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log json;
```

You can use Fluentd to parse it and stream it into BigQuery directly. Here's the example repo: https://github.com/markhilton/docker-fluent-bigquery

Another option is to stream standard Nginx logs into BigQuery and then use REGEXP_EXTRACT to parse it and extract specific data fields.

I use GKE Nginx Ingress to stream logs into BigQuery, connected as a data source for Google Data Studio to render reports. In Data Studio I added custom formula fields using REGEXP_EXTRACT to access specific metrics from Nginx log payload.